# How to save GridView filters for pagination in Yii2

Tags: php, gridview, pagination, yii2

There is a page where the GridView is displayed:

```php
// OrderController

public function actionIndex()
{
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => Model::find(),
        'sort' => false,
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 15,
            'route' => '/order'
        ],
    ]);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

There are buttons on the page that filter the information in the table. When you click on them, an Ajax request is sent to the *loadData* method with the necessary parameters. Then the result is displayed on the page.

```php
// OrderController

public function actionLoadData()
{
    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;

    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax)
    {
        ...

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => Model::find()->accounts($selectedAccountsIds)
            'sort' => false,
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 15,
                'route' => '/order'
            ],
        ]);
        
        return [
            'success' => true,
            'render' => $this->renderPartial('parts/_table', [
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider
            ])
        ];
    }

    ...
}
```

The GridView is wrapped in Pjax so that the pagination works without reloading.

```php
<?php Pjax::begin(['timeout' => 5000]) ?>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <?= GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
           ...
        ]); ?>
    </div>
<?php Pjax::end() ?>
```

And now, in fact, the problem itself. The easiest way to describe it is in the form of steps:

1. The page loaded, the data was taken from *actionIndex()*
2. The user clicked on the button, sent an Ajax request to *actionLoadData()*
3. Rendering of a new GridView
4. **When you click on the pagination, data is loaded from *actionIndex()* without filters**

It is logical, because with page-by-page navigation, the request will go to *actionIndex()*. The question is, how do I tell *actionIndex()* that the data needs to be retrieved with filters in mind?

I have only 2 options in my head. The first is to add filter information to the URL parameters using JavaScript after a successful Ajax request, for example *...&daterange=week*, and in *actionIndex()*, get them and do the necessary manipulations. The second one is the same, but with cookies.

```php
// actionIndex() - Example with GET params
if (Yii::$app->request->isPjax)
{
    $dateRange = Yii::$app->request->get('dateRange');
    ...
}
```

I created a JavaScript function that adds the necessary parameters to the url. And after an ajax request, my URL looks like this:

```
http://site.loc/order?selected_ids=%5B1%2C4%5D
```

But, if you look at the links that are formed for pagination, they look like this:

```
http://site.loc/order?page=2
```

And I need them to look like this:

```
http://site.loc/order?selected_ids=%5B1%2C4%5D&page=2
```

In *actionIndex()* and *actionLoadData()* I changed route parameter to this:

```php
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => Model::find(),
        'sort' => false,
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 15,
            'route' => '/order' . Yii::$app->request->queryString
        ],
    ]);
```

But this only broke the URL even more... There is only one option left with cookies, but it also seems doubtful to me.

**If someone has encountered a similar problem, please share your experience. Thanks!**

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem by using cookies. When the page is initially loaded, it is checked for the presence of cookies, if there are any, then the data is taken with the necessary filters, if there are none, then default filters are set. As a nice bonus, the filter settings are saved after the page is reloaded:)